# How to connect to a proxy to get different IP Address on Android Virtual Device using Appium?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, appium, appium-android

I am trying to make my mobile application go through a proxy so that I can have a different ip address. Below are my attempt and it's not working. It's still giving me my own Ip address. How can I make my Android application go through appium server and then go through a proxy server?

I am using Proxy Manager from BrightData. it allow me to input all my proxies (host:port:username:password) and rotate it automatically. Proxy Manager give me a port to use which connect to those rotated proxies. Eventually I just want to use (host:port:username:password) but I don't know how to authenticate correctly

```
    // Proxy Manager port which connect me to different proxies
    String proxystring = "127.0.0.1:24000";   

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setSslProxy(proxystring);
    proxy.setHttpProxy(proxystring);
    
    File appDir = new File("src");
    File app = new File(appDir, "WhatismyIPaddress_v3.02_apkpure.com.apk");
            
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel 3 API 30");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    
    //127.0.0.1:4723 is the ip:port of appium server.
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium seems not support proxing itself, but it's possible to configure proxy for android emulator programmatically passing next args:

```
-http-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<machineName>:<port>
```

> The -http-proxy option forces the emulator to use the specified HTTP/HTTPS proxy for all outgoing TCP connections. Redirection for UDP is not currently supported.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#proxy

To make it work in your test script try to add `avdArgs` capability:

uiautomator2 doc says about `avdArgs` capability value.

> Either a string or an array of emulator command line arguments.

Try something like this, but I'm not fully sure, maybe to pass proxy you'll have to pass string array, not string.

```
cap.setCapability("avdArgs",  "-http-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<machineName>:<port>");
```